# Java Constructor Objection Initialization

Tags: java, oop

I'm solving random online java problems. I'm stuck with an OOP problem. The statement is

> This second constructor should create Move[] objects and pass to the
>   third constructor.

What is meant by this? According to my rudimentary knowledge, we can't create new objects within a constructor, can we?

Comment: Why not? You just use ```new``` like everywhere else. You can't make a new object using the constructor you are currently in (which makes sense) but everything else is fine.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the Task? It is hard to help you if we don't know what the rest of the code looks like.

Comment: You can definitely create objects within a constructor.

Comment: @NeilLocketz That's not necessarily true... if there are multiple constructors for the class you can create a new object of the type you are constructing.

Comment: @MatthewDiana Yes, but from the question I think the person was learning about constructer overloading, so they probably already new about that.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from creating the same type in a single constructor, other than the inevitable stack overflow? (Hard to test on my phone.)

Comment: @shmosel Its a part of problem statement so I'm just following the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(Bar[] bars) {
        ...
    }
}
```

We can make another ctor call `Foo(Bar[] bars)` by writing `this(...)` as the first line:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() {
        this(new Bar[]{});
    }
    Foo(Bar[] bars) {
        ...
    }
}
```